# How do I convert screen space to world space coords in Bevy using Camera2dComponents?

Tags: rust, bevy

Using `Res<Events<CursorMoved>>` I can get the mouse position change in screen space coordinates (zero in bottom-left corner), e.g.

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct State {
    cursor_moved_reader: EventReader<CursorMoved>,
}

fn set_mouse_pos(mut state: ResMut<State>, cursor_moved: Res<Events<CursorMoved>>) {
    for event in state.cursor_moved_reader.iter(&cursor_moved) {
        println!("cursor: {:?}", event.position);
    }
}
```

The question now is if I set `SpriteComponents`' `transform.translation` to the cursor position when using a camera from `Camera2dComponents::default()` a sprite with position `0, 0` is rendered in the center of the screen. What's the idiomatic way of converting between the screen space mouse coords and the camera world space coords?

Comment: Don't think there's something idiomatic. Seems like you'll have to interpolate 0 to 1 interval of screen space (or 0 to max_pixel_idx, depending on convention) to -1 to 1 interval of camera space. That's just a linear interpolation, e.g. `camera_x = screen_x/max_screen_x * 2.0 - 1.0`

Comment: I believe [this](https://github.com/jamadazi/bevy-cookbook/blob/master/bevy-cookbook.md#convert-screen-coordinates-to-world-coordinates) may help

Comment: The cheat book has moved to [here](https://bevy-cheatbook.github.io/cookbook/cursor2world.html). I've also added an answer for that link, because I think this is the best reference, and it's kind of hidden in this comment here.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer seems to be on the right track, however the transformation is not fully implemented and actually overengineered. Stumbled on the same problem and figured that's what the camera transform is for! This works for me:

```rust
fn window_to_world(
    position: Vec2,
    window: &Window,
    camera: &Transform,
) -> Vec3 {

    // Center in screen space
    let norm = Vec3::new(
        position.x - window.width() / 2.,
        position.y - window.height() / 2.,
        0.,
    );

    // Apply camera transform
    *camera * norm

    // Alternatively:
    //camera.mul_vec3(norm)
}
```

Comment: How do I obtain the camera `Transform`? Suppose I use `OrthographicCameraBundle::new_2d()`.

Comment: You use a query like `transform: Query<&Transform, With<Camera>>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar confusion when I first started hacking with `bevy`.  Here's what I am currently using to translate from window to world coordinates (for a 2D game):

```rust
fn window_to_world(
    window: &Window,
    camera: &Transform,
    position: &Vec2,
) -> Vec3 {
    let center = camera.translation.truncate();
    let half_width = (window.width() / 2.0) * camera.scale.x;
    let half_height = (window.height() / 2.0) * camera.scale.y;
    let left = center.x - half_width;
    let bottom = center.y - half_height;
    Vec3::new(
        left + position.x * camera.scale.x,
        bottom + position.y * camera.scale.y,
        0.0,  // I'm working in 2D
    )
}
```

In `bevy`, the `Window` coordinate system has the origin `(0, 0)` at the *bottom left*, measured in pixels, and increasing as you go *up* the screen.  The `Camera`'s coordinates default to `(0, 0)` in the *center* of the window, measured in whichever unit makes the most sense for your game.

This function is limited because it doesn't take rotation of the camera into account, only the scale.